# Functions do not complete their task correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a question, because I don't understand why my functions don't give me the correct results.

I have a main function `stopClick()` in which I launch two other functions, they are similar but I pass two different array and create two different array :

`this.timestampCheckDestro(this.props.arrayTimestampDestro)` give me `tempoRealeDestro`
`this.timestampCheckDestro(this.props.arrayTimestampDestro)` give me `tempoRealeSinistro`

From the results obtained, I noticed that the function that starts first is able to fill the array up to a certain point and then fill it with NaN values. On the contrary, the second array either consists of only NaN or the initial positions are NaN and the final ones are filled with values.

My code is this:

```
async stopClick(){
  //Code...
   await this.timestampCheckDestro(this.props.arrayTimestampDestro);
   await this.timestampCheckSinistro(this.props.arrayTimestampSinistro);
  //Actions to another function. (after I have the array populated from the two functions)
}

async  timestampCheckDestro( timestampDestro ){
   //declare variable
  for( let i = 0; i < timestampDestro.length; i++){
       diffDestro = (( baseDestro + timestampDestro[i] ) - this.contatoreDestro )
    this.tempoRealeDestro.push(diffDestro)
  } 
 }

async timestampCheckSinistro( timestampSinistro ){
   //declare variable
  for( let i = 0; i < timestampSinistro.length; i++){
       diffSinistro = (( baseSinistro + timestampSinistro[i] ) - this.contatoreSinistro )
    this.tempoRealeSinistro.push(diffSinistro)
  } 
 }
```

Now my question is:
I don't know if I used correctly async/await or if useless in a problem of this type, in any case I would like to understand how to perform the two functions and only when they have completed all the operations to carry on the execution of the function.

Thank you

EDIT:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    };
   //....

    this.tempoRealeDestro = [];
    this.tempoRealeSinistro = [];
}

dataReceived(){
    this.dimensioneArrayRaggiunta = this.props.dimensioneArrayRaggiunta;
     if(this.checkContatore == false){
       this.contatoreDestro = this.props.contatoreTimestampDestro;
       this.contatoreSinistro = this.props.contatoreTimestampSinistro;
       this.checkContatore = true;
     }
 this.stopClick();
}
```

Comment: you've basically used async/await where it's not needed - nothing asyncrhonous and no promises at all - your issue is mishandling of the daya in this.props.arrayTimestamp* and whatever those other properties are (this.contatero*)

Comment: `async/await` is just for easier handling of promises. Your code isn't asynchronous, it's linear. So there is no need for `async/await` at all.

Comment: Ok, in fact I get the same results as when I wasn't using them. But how do you think I could do to achieve this?

Comment: Why dont you put console.log inside the for loops and figure out what is NaN value? I think arrayTimestampDestro or arrayTimestampSinistro contain NaN values in it.

Comment: @NhutDinhBa Hi and thank you for your answer, arrayTimestampDestro and arrayTimestampSinistro are correctly populated. What I noticed is that:
For example arrayTimestampDestro and arrayTimestampSinistro have  a length of 30, 
so tempoRealeDestro for the first 15 have a value the other 15 are NaN, while for tempoRealeSinistro the first 15 are NaN the last 15 have a value

Comment: As if the two functions were interrupted or waited before leaving.

Comment: Could you show us how you set things up? In particular tempoRealeSinistro/Destro?

Comment: @AHaworth Hi and thank you for your answer, I edit my question :)